# Returning the name value from the dropdown list and not the id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I have a TEAM (id,name) model which stores a list of 20 teams. I also have a FIXTURE (date, home_team, away_team) model to be used for the admin to set up the week fixtures and within this I wish to get the name of the team from a dropdown list. I have managed to get a team populated dropdown list on the new fixture page but when I am saving the selections it is returning the ID and not the NAME as I had hoped. My code is as follows:

`<%= f.collection_select(:home_team, :team_id , @Team, :id, :blank_include  => "-Select Home Team-" %>`

Any ideas on how I could return the name value?

The dropdowns currently display: Arsenal, Aston Villa, Bolton etc....

When I select the team from my dropdown in my _new.html.erb form it is the listing it on the _index.html.erb page as 1 & 2 not the name of the team which is what I was hoping for.

I have not got the  `Team.find_by_name(params[:team_nam])` in my code so I am unsure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You would want the ID returned, why would you waste time doing this:

`Team.find_by_name(params[:team_name])`

When you could just do this:

`Team.find(params[:team_id])`

Comment: Please see my edited post. I do not have the line you mention in my code

Comment: Thats pesudo code, false code. Why would you want to return the name?